# Pass parameters to Visual workflow part2?

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

I think/hope this question will be a good complement to the question:
[How do I pass parameters to a Visual Workflow?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-visual-workflow)
I am trying to pass a url param to populate a flow using the information on this [post](http://vchhablani.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/populate-flow-variable-from-a-url-parameter-visual-flow/), but it doesn't work as when the form is loaded the input field is empty, basically I have set up my URL like:
https://ap1.salesforce.com/flow/Update_Merchandise?testvar=test

and the input field like this:
 [image]

Comment: how do you define the testvar variable? i think it should be setup as "input and output" and not as "private"?

Comment: Hi Ian, for purpose of this example the variable will be defined via URL, ie:https://ap1.salesforce.com/flow/Update_Merchandise?testvar=test
where testvar = test, now in real life example i was thinking in possible 2 scenarios from a table displayed in a VF where the user select a link that brings the info of that particular record (ie ID of that record or something), or the other option will be depending on the log in user. I need to explore how feasible will be implementing this

Comment: Ian's right. The variable should be setup as at least "input" for it to accept the url parameter

Comment: Hi RohanC, thank you for the comment, I think now I am confused, what do you mean by at least "input" I believe the field test Param is an input of type text.

Comment: Might be a bit late, but the variable must be defined in the flow itself (at the left side, tab 'Resources'. There you define the variable testvar and make it an "input and output" variable. Hope this helps.