# Passing id to detail page button

Tags: visualforce, id

I have a scenario where I need to link a lead to another lead if both are related by relation, for ex, a spouse. I created a custom lookup field to link both leads. But if a lead needs to add a spouse then I provided a detail button with url that allows to create a new Lead. Something like `/apex/InboundScriptsLead?subflow=CreateNewLead`. I can create a new lead this way but I want the lead id from the previous page to be set to this new Lead as spouse after it gets created. Can anyone let me know how can this be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE BUB. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Comment: Can't you add one more parameter like `/apex/InboundScriptsLead?subflow=CreateNewLead&LeadID=18 digit Id` ?

Comment: Related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, create a Variable called spouseLeadId with a Data Type of Text, and an Input/Output type of at least Input Only. Then, you can specify the parameter in your flow:interview:

```
<flow:interview interview="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.subflow}">
    <apex:param name="spouseLeadId" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.spouseLeadId}" />
</flow:interview>
```

Finally, just add it to your flow's URL:

```
/apex/InboundScriptsLead?subflow=CreateNewLead&spouseLeadId={!Lead.Id}
```